# LBCookieStickinessPolicy - cloudformation

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am not able to set LBCookieStickinessPolicy for ELB using the cloudformation script.

```
"LBCookieStickinessPolicy": [
      {
        "PolicyName": "Sample",
        "CookieExpirationPeriod": "180"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Which error do you get? Is this fragment of code inside the LoadBalancer Properties?

Comment: Yes, the above part is added to the LB properties. I didnt get any error, the LB is launched without the LB policy.

Comment: That looks just fine, so there must be something else going wrong during the create/update of your stack.

Comment: @kavin So what was the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate this policy with a listener. Include the policy name in the listener's PolicyNames property.

```
"LBCookieStickinessPolicy" : [{
      "PolicyName" : "Sample",
      "CookieExpirationPeriod" : "180"
    } ],
    "Listeners" : [ {
      "LoadBalancerPort" : "80",
      "InstancePort" : { "Ref" : "InstancePort" },
      "Protocol" : "HTTP",
      "PolicyNames" : [ "Sample" ]
    } ],
```

Comment: I didn't understand the solution. I already had in listeners "PolicyNames", because I used protocol HTTPS. And then to add the same "PolicyName" in  "LBCookieStickinessPolicy"? Because it fails with error:  "Policy names starting with [ELBSample-, ELBSecurityPolicy-] are reserved". It looks that he trying to create new policy, and fails because I already have one with this name. Do you why it happens?

Comment: You need to cross reference the policy that you are creating in the stack to ELB listener.

In this case, Cloudformation will create stickiness policy with the name "Sample" and when ELB creation happens, ELB listener will find policy with name "Sample" and attach that policy to ELB.